# Bad results from perceptron algorithm

Tags: java, machine-learning, perceptron

I have this perceptron algorithm for classifiyng movement data from a sensor:

```
    //vector data from sensors
    double inputs[][] = new double[nofall_data.size() + fall_data.size()][nofall_data.get(0).length];
    //sets fall or no fall for corresponding inputs
    int outputs[] = new int[nofall_data.size() + fall_data.size()];

    //initialize weights
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        weights[i] = r.nextDouble();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
        int totalError = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < outputs.length; j++) {    // = ~5.000-10.000
            //classifiy object
            int output = classifyInt(inputs[j], false);
            //calculate error
            int error = output - outputs[j];  
            //sum of errors
            totalError += error;

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { //n = 4
                //weight is unchanged if there is no error, else change it
                weights[k] += inputs[j][k] * lrate * error;
            }

        }
        i++;

        //done if there are no errors
        if (totalError == 0) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(i));
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "classifying completed with no errors");
            break;
        }
    }
```

And classifyInt:

```
 private int classifyInt(double[] input, boolean b) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        sum += weights[i] * input[i];
    }
    //(just for debugging)
    if (b) {
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    if (sum > threshold)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

If I dont't add the maxIterations condition it runs forever. If i stop after let's say 50k iterations the results aren't satisfying (almost every new data is put in the wrong class). The system gets accleration data from a sensor and is supposed to classify new data in fall or no fall for a fall detection system. 
I've tried the same with a Nearest-Neighbor algorithm from the Java-ML library and it works perfectly. I wanted to try the pereceptron to have something to compare it to.
Did I get something in the algorithm wrong? lrate was always set to 1 and the threshold to 0.

Comment: I'm not sure under what conditions you'd expect `totalError` to be exactly 0 (e.g. I don't know the weights, input data, threshold etc. and I'm not familiar with that kind of algorithm) but is it intended that an equal number of positive (you expected 0 but got 1) and negative errors  (you expected 1 but got 0) lead to a total error of 0?

Comment: Btw, you're not just initializing `inputs` and `outputs` but also actually fill them, right?

Comment: Many problems cannot be solved by a percepron. Even if they can, the learning process will normally not result in an error of exactly zero.

Comment: I'm filling them also, just didn't copy the part. Maybe the data isn't seperable by a simple linear function? What other machine learning algorithm could i use?

Comment: The problem might be setting `threshold` to 0 which might result in `classifyInt()` almost always returning 1. Thus if the corresponding `outputs[j]` is 0 you'll get `error = 1` and thus increase `weights[k]`. That in turn might lead to an even higher probability for `classifyInt()` to return 1. You'll probably be able to see how that spirals up and up and up.

Comment: What would be a better value?

Comment: I'd say that depends on your data and might need some fine tuning. You might also have to adjust the weight calculation. Currently it seems as if when you expect 0 but get 1 you'll get `error` = 1 and thus increase the weights when you actually should decrease them. On the other hand when you expect 1 but get 0 you'll get `error` = -1 and thus decrease the weights (due to multiplying with `error`) when you actually should increase them. As I said I'm no expert here but a simple `int error = outputs[j] - output;` might already be sufficient.